# onClick - fire only if the its div is the target

Tags: reactjs

```
<div onClick={someParentFunc}>
    <div onClick={someChildFunc}></div>
</div>
```

Should you click on the child, both functions get called. Which is expected.

Please tell me the most convenient way to fire someParentFunc only if the parent div is the event's target.

The two current solutions I've got is to...

- useRef to reference the parent div and, in its onClick, check it against the event's target
- call stopPropagation in the child's callback

...both of which seem terribly inconvenient.

Comment: `stopPropagation` seems the right solution for this. Why do you think it is inconvenient?

Comment: @PrakashSharma What if I want to fire a third ancestor's callback? (Well, on second thought, I might just use a capturing event in the third ancestor.)

Comment: @JohnSmith I suggest you to use css style for `pointer-events`

Comment: In that case, comparing the event target seems the right option to me.